# Extract value from string collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a string collection like this

```
SetDEL_Stores.Add(DealerCode + "," + ItemIdentityCode.Text + "," + decimal.Parse(Qty.Text) + "," + DateTime.ParseExact(ExpireDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "," + BatchNumber.Text);

InsertDEL_Stores(SetDEL_Stores);
```

after pass values to the `SetDEL_Stores` (my string collection), collection is

```
"S0010M,AZI002M,3,12/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,VDIQ20"
```

in this case I'm using one value from this collection, as a parameter with SQL query

```
    private void InsertDEL_Stores(StringCollection SC_PurLinr)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        const String strQuery = "SELECT BatchNumber FROM DEL_Stores WHERE BatchNumber = @BatchNumber";
        SqlConnection conPR = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmdPR = new SqlCommand();
        cmdPR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", SC_PurLinr.IndexOf("4"));
        cmdPR.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdPR.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmdPR.Connection = conPR;

            conPR.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmdPR.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = sdr["BatchNumber"].ToString();
            }

            conPR.Close();
            conPR.Dispose();
     }
```

After execution I'm getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'VDIQ20' to data type int.

It points to the line

```
while (sdr.Read())
```

But if I set the parameter like `cmdPR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", "VDIQ20");` as normal I can take the correct value to expected textbox

What can I do to fix this problem? Please help me ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

I think you have a few more problems going on.  You are passing your entire StringCollection to this method when you should be passing a single string.  I don't think you need to use a StringCollection in this case.

Something like:

```
var singleItem = SC_PurLinr[0]; 
InsertDEL_Stores(singleItem);
```

Change your method to:

```
private void InsertDEL_Stores(string singleItem)

....

cmdPR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", singleItem.Split(',')[4]);
```

Comment: getting an error like   Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @Smith, I think you should be using just a `string` and not a `StringCollection`. See my edit; I will update.

Comment: Bah was racing to this... just saw it in his collection.  Only one string.  So obvious!  Nice ;)

Answer (score 2):

`SC_PurLinr.IndexOf("4")` does not return what I think you think. It returns int, not string.

In case of your example string it doesn't find "4" and it returns -1.

So your query is
`"SELECT BatchNumber FROM DEL_Stores WHERE BatchNumber = -1"`

In order to check if `BatchNumber = -1` database converts BatchNumber (nvarchar) to int but it can't and that's why you receive this error.

Instead you should index the `StringCollection` to get element you want not call `IndexOf` method.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Peri's answer.  (Edited to correct the index of BatchNumber)

If you are trying to access the 4th string (`StringCollection` is a zero indexed collection type).  You will need to do something like this.

```
cmdPR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", SC_PurLinr[3]);
```

That will give you the 4th value of `SC_PurLinr` which looks like it is the batch number you are looking for.

Comment: getting an error   like Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: yes @Evan lewis ,, i tryed the solution (SC_PurLinr[3]) ant no getting error like Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Check the size of your collection in the debugger using a breakpoint.  Make sure that you are trying to access the last value (which looks like it's your batch number).  Change the value in `SC_PurLinr[n]` to the index value of the BatchNumber you are looking for.  Also make sure you are passing the full string collection to the method.

Comment: @Smith read Brad's answer above, my solution would work if you indeed had 4 values in your collection.  But you are only adding one string.

Answer (score 0):

`.IndexOf("4")` returns an `int`, not a `string`.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, I already said that 6 minutes ago. What is the point of giving the same answer?

Comment: Really, how about I'm sitting at a desk talking and it took me a few min to figure out the problem. It's not like this auto refreshes. Great way to lose people for attempting to help though. Great job. I'll be sure not to help anymore.  And your change was at 17:58 where mine was at 18:02, that is 4 minutes, since you can't seem to count.   More than one person can hit a page and answer around the same time you know.